# Getting undefined method `param_key' for "ModelName":ActiveModel::Name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, refinerycms

My application was running fine with ruby 1.9.2 -p290, rails 3.0.10 & refinerycms 1.0.9.
I have used acts_as_commentable gem for comments. I have added a new gem and run bundle install, after that I am not able to add comment. It is throwing below error

```
undefined method `param_key' for "ModelName":ActiveModel::Name
```

I have also commented the newly added gem and run bundle install. But still the issue persists. Following are the result for 
    bundle show

```
        * abstract (1.0.0)
        * actionmailer (3.0.10)
        * actionpack (3.0.10)
        * active_utils (2.0.1)
        * activemerchant (1.39.2)
        * activemodel (3.0.10)
        * activerecord (3.0.10)
        * activeresource (3.0.10)
        * activesupport (3.0.10)
        * acts-as-taggable-on (2.4.1)
        * acts_as_commentable (4.0.0)
        * acts_as_indexed (0.8.3)
        * acts_as_list (0.1.9)
        * addressable (2.3.5)
        * after_load (0.0.1)
        * ajaxful_rating (3.0.0.beta6)
        * ansi (1.4.3)
        * archive-tar-minitar (0.5.2)
        * arel (2.0.10)
        * awesome_nested_set (2.1.6)
        * awesome_print (1.2.0)
        * aws-s3 (0.6.3)
        * babosa (0.3.11)
        * bcrypt-ruby (3.1.2)
        * browser (0.2.1)
        * builder (2.1.2)
        * bundler (1.3.5)
        * capybara (1.1.4)
        * capybara-webkit (0.12.1)
        * childprocess (0.3.9)
        * columnize (0.3.6)
        * cucumber (1.3.8)
        * cucumber-rails (1.0.6)
        * database_cleaner (1.2.0)
        * decent_exposure (2.3.0)
        * devise (1.4.9)
        * devise_invitable (0.6.0)
        * diff-lcs (1.2.4)
        * dragonfly (0.9.12)
        * erubis (2.6.6)
        * exception_notification (3.0.1)
        * excon (0.27.6)
        * factory_girl (4.2.0)
        * factory_girl_rails (4.2.1)
        * ffi (1.9.0)
        * filters_spam (0.3)
        * fog (1.16.0)
        * formatador (0.2.4)
        * friendly_id_globalize3 (3.2.1.6)
        * fuubar (1.2.1)
        * galetahub-simple_captcha (0.1.3)
        * gherkin (2.12.2)
        * globalize3 (0.3.0)
        * hashr (0.0.22)
        * httparty (0.11.0)
        * i18n (0.5.0)
        * jquery-rails (1.0.19)
        * json (1.8.1)
        * json_pure (1.8.1)
        * kgio (2.8.1)
        * launchy (2.3.0)
        * linecache19 (0.5.12)
        * mail (2.2.20)
        * mime-types (1.25)
        * mini_portile (0.5.1)
        * money (5.0.0)
        * multi_json (1.8.2)
        * multi_test (0.0.2)
        * multi_xml (0.5.5)
        * mysql2 (0.2.20)
        * net-scp (1.1.2)
        * net-ssh (2.7.0)
        * nokogiri (1.6.0)
        * orm_adapter (0.0.7)
        * paper_trail (2.7.2)
        * pickle (0.4.11)
        * polyglot (0.3.3)
        * puma (2.6.0)
        * pushmeup (0.1.2)
        * rack (1.2.8)
        * rack-cache (1.2)
        * rack-mount (0.6.14)
        * rack-rewrite (1.0.2)
        * rack-test (0.5.7)
        * rails (3.0.10)
        * railties (3.0.10)
        * raindrops (0.12.0)
        * rake (10.1.0)
        * rdoc (3.12.2)
        * refinerycms (1.0.9)
        * refinerycms-authentication (1.0.9)
        * refinerycms-banners (1.0)
        * refinerycms-base (1.0.9)
        * refinerycms-blog (1.6.2)
        * refinerycms-calendar (1.1.0)
        * refinerycms-core (1.0.9)
        * refinerycms-dashboard (1.0.9)
        * refinerycms-generators (1.0.4)
        * refinerycms-i18n (0.9.9.16)
        * refinerycms-images (1.0.9)
        * refinerycms-inquiries (1.0.1)
        * refinerycms-memberships (1.0)
        * refinerycms-news (1.2.0)
        * refinerycms-newsletter_sponsers (1.0)
        * refinerycms-search (0.9.8)
        * refinerycms-settings (1.0.9)
        * refinerycms-testing (1.0.9)
        * rest-client (1.6.7)
        * routing-filter (0.3.1)
        * rspec (2.14.1)
        * rspec-core (2.14.6)
        * rspec-expectations (2.14.3)
        * rspec-instafail (0.2.4)
        * rspec-mocks (2.14.4)
        * rspec-rails (2.14.0)
        * ruby-debug-base19 (0.11.25)
        * ruby-debug19 (0.11.6)
        * ruby-hmac (0.4.0)
        * ruby-progressbar (1.2.0)
        * ruby_core_source (0.1.5)
        * rubyzip (0.9.9)
        * selenium-webdriver (2.35.1)
        * sendgrid (1.2.0)
        * seo_meta (1.1.1)
        * shoulda-matchers (2.4.0)
        * slim (2.0.1)
        * spork (0.9.2)
        * sqlite3 (1.3.8)
        * temple (0.6.7)
        * thor (0.14.6)
        * tilt (1.4.1)
        * tire (0.6.1)
        * treetop (1.4.15)
        * truncate_html (0.9.2)
        * tzinfo (0.3.38)
        * unicode (0.4.4)
        * unicorn (4.4.0)
        * warden (1.0.6)
        * websocket (1.0.7)
        * will_paginate (3.0.5)
        * xml-simple (1.1.2)
        * xpath (0.1.4)
```

Following are the error msg displaying on the console

```
Started POST "/comments" for 192.168.2.170 at 2013-10-16 10:24:35 +0000
Processing by CommentsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"â", "authenticity_token"=>"Aql7Dz5cfx96Yi8JpBH5wIux+EGDdTGh98ksA97CbN4=", "comment"=>{"comment"=>"Test comment", "commentable_id"=>"1518", "commentable_type"=>"AuditProgram"}, "commit"=>"Create Comment", "locale"=>:en}

Exception, redirecting: undefined method `param_key' for "AuditProgram":ActiveModel::Name
Rendered public/404.html within layouts/application (313.7ms)
Completed 404 Not Found in 680ms (Views: 313.1ms | ActiveRecord: 121.3ms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue by downgrade the **decent_exposure** gem.

This issue raised because of the upgrade of the **decent_exposure** gem to its latest release, which is not supported by my application env and also it is used internally by the refinerycms.

Added the gem explicitly into the **Gemfile** with the version which is support by my application environment.

Answer (score 1):

try adding this line in your model/class

> extend ActiveModel::Naming

Comment: Not fix my issue. Added the same in the model and in controller but getting the same error. When after bundle installed, this error is coming. Before that it was working fine...

Comment: the problem is sumthing else, you are considering it as a gem problem.
describe the error screen more or share some screen shot of error screen..

Comment: Added detail appearing on the console, with the question.